# ODEs Why have I got $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ eigenvectors

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, solution-verification

any help at figuring out why I have received a certain result/where I have gone wrong for the following question:

For the Dynamical System
$\ \dot{x}=yx^2 -x$.
$\ \dot{y}=-xy-x^2y+4y^2+4xy^2$.
Determine the Jacobian matrix and calculate eigenvalues, for each equilibrium point. For real eigenvalues, calculate the eigenvectors.

I have four equilibirum points $(0,0),(-1,-1),(2,\frac{1}{2}),(-2,-\frac{1}{2})$. But I am struggling with the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for the last equilibrium point $(-2,-\frac{1}{2})$

Here is my solution so far:
$\ X=x+2 \Rightarrow x=X-2$.
$\ Y=y+\frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow y=Y-\frac{1}{2}$.
$\ A=\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}=2yx-1 \text{ so at } (-2,-\frac{1}{2}), A=1$.
$\ B=\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=x^2 \text{ so at } (-2,-\frac{1}{2}), B=4$.
$\ C=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=-y-2yx+4y^2 \text{ so at } (-2,-\frac{1}{2}), C=-\frac{1}{2}$.
$\ D=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial y}=-x-x^2+8y+8xy \text{ so at } (-2,-\frac{1}{2}), D=2$.

This gives us Jacobian
$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 4 \\
   -\frac{1}{2} & 2
\end{bmatrix}$

$\ \det(J-\lambda I)=0\Rightarrow  
0=\begin{vmatrix}
1-\lambda & 4 \\ 
-\frac{1}{2} & 2-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}=
  (1-\lambda)(2-\lambda)-4(-\frac{1}{2})=\lambda^2 -3\lambda +4 = (\lambda -4)(\lambda +1) $.
This gives us eigenvalues $\lambda _1 =4$ and $\lambda _2 =-1$
However, when I then sub these into $(J-\lambda I)\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}=0$, I get $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ eigenvectors which (I think) aren't possible??

Can anyone see where I may have gone wrong and put me on the right path? Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you explain what you did to get the eigenvectors? It sounds like you got confused and plugged the eigenvalues back into the determinant and got zero (meaning that you found the right eigenvalues) but this isn't how you find eigenvectors.

Comment: $\lambda^2 -3\lambda +4 \neq (\lambda -4)(\lambda +1)$. The eigenvalues are not real.

Comment: Hi Ian, sorry I used $(J-\lambda I)\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}=0$ to get the eigenvectors, I just typed it incorrectly!

Comment: Dennis Thank you so much! Such a stupid mistake

Comment: It has happened to us all. You're welcome.

Comment: As a reminder, when you use your method to find the eigenvector, and end up finding only $[0,0[$, when you **very likely** make an mistake in finding the eigenvalues.

Comment: Yes, if you find that the only "eigenvector" for your apparent "eigenvalue" is the zero vector, and your solution of the linear system is correct, then your apparent eigenvalue was incorrect to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to leave the question up to help someone in the future.

From the comments, please note that if your eigenvalue has a zero vector "eigenvector", and the linear system is correct, the eigenvalue was incorrect to begin with.

My actual eigenvalues were
$\ \lambda_{1,2}=\frac{3 \pm \sqrt{7}i}{2}$.